# New table (with derived_data) or SQL query?

Tags: mysql, database-design, derived-types

From a best-practice point of view, is it better to create a new table in my database with a derived_data field from other tables, or calculate it using an SQL-query everytime?

DETAILS:
More precicely, i have a table `ORDERS(id_order,date,time,sum)` and i want to track the daily profits and preview them everytime an administrator selects it from a drop-down menu. Shall i make an SQL-query everytime he asks for it, or a new table `PROFITS(date,day_profit)`with a derived_data field that takes its value from other tables?

Comment: You could create a view

Comment: There is no "best practice" for this situation.  It depends on your application requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For simple calculations (`a+b`), do them in the `SELECT`.

For aggregates (`COUNT(sales), SUM(revenue)`) where the results are regularly calculate, build "Summary Table(s)".

For example, daily counts, totals, etc, broken down by `region`.  It would otherwise take a `GROUP BY`, etc.

Note that you can compute weekly or monthly totals from a daily table, so do not build more tables.

See [my Summary Tables blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

For a thousand rows, this is not important; for a million or a billion it is vital to performance in "Data Warehousing".

Keep in mind that a Summary Table is a no-no (to Database purists) since it holds 'redundant' data.  So your policies should avoid letting it get out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of few pros and cons of each technique based on which one can decide which one should be used when:

**Summary table**: Commonly used in Data Warehouses to give a performance boost for select queries.

1. When summarized data is reusable.
2. The aggregate query is not
   performing well because of large amount of low granularity data it
   is processing in source table.

**Direct Query**

1. When data is not reused at multiple time / places
2. User needs real time data on every execution. Summary table will need separate loading logic which will need to be scheduled periodically, which will introduce lag. Also the summary table would need to be refreshed as a batch from last data updated in source table.

**Combination of both**:
Create a summary table at day level which gets refreshed say at midnight. Select the aggregated data from this summary table and union this with live data from source table of summary table which came after midnight. Similarly summary tables could have granular level of week / month / year or all of them in separate table depending on amount of incoming data and its re-usability.